# Bug in Android Studio Gradle 3.6.1 with Retrofit Gson library

Tags: android, android-studio

There is a bug after upgrading Android Studio to 3.6.1. App is continuously crashing `onResponse()` of retrofit call. May be the problem with `Converter Gson` but I don't know exactly. I just downgraded gradle(project level) to 3.5.3 and its working perfectly now.

Exception is:

```
getVideoList$1.onResponse (VideoListActivity.java:17)
retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:37)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7682)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:516)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

And I am using retrofit libraries:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

Well these libraries are working perfectly in `Gradle` 3.5.3 but crashes in 3.6.1 so, I don't know exact bug but there is and asking this question for help. If any buddy know what is the problem then we need to report it Retrofit or Android Studio.

Comment: Yes. We also using newer version of  Android Studio. Thanks to warn!

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I also encountered a similar problem,  when minifyEnable=true, Gson cannot parse json data.

Comment: Nope! I am currently using Android Studio 3.6.2 but using Gradle 3.5.3!